# How to build a weekwise caldendar in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I'm trying to build a weekwise calendar, which displays 7 days of the current week so I can create new and see existing events.

I'm not sure what is the correct way to build this calendar. Should I get the system time first and then calculate what 7 days are in the current week? If so, how can I get system time in Rails.

If not, can any one give some better suggestions?

I was trying to use some plugin but none of them seems satisfactory so I'm building my own.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the fullcalendar.js (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) - I was able to get a calendar in my Rails app in a very short time.